# Error: Could not find or load main class NewClass Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: NewClass

Tags: java

this is a java program that i try some data structure things to develop my skill in coding but while do that i face the above error. I tried different steps but it wont work. what is wrong in this code?

```
// check all stack function (inbuilt)

import java.util.*;
class StackFunction{

        // create object and constructors
        
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        Stack<String> name = new Stack<String>();
        
        //declare/initialize values/variables;
        
        char opt,d;
        
        
        //program starts
        
        
        do{
            System.out.println("Enter your option:");   System.out.println("(A)push "+"(B)pop   "+"(C)peek  "+"(D)empty "+"(E)search    "+"(F)display");
            opt = s.next().charAt(0);
            switch(opt){
                case 'A':
                    System.out.println("Push Option");
                    System.out.println("Enter the name:");
                    name.push(s.nextLine());
                    System.out.println(name);
                    break;
                case 'B':
                    if(name.empty()) System.out.println("Stack is empty");
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Pop option");
                        String store = name.pop();
                        System.out.println("poped name: "+store);
                        System.out.println(name);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'C':
                    if(name.empty()) System.out.println("Stack is empty");
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Peak Value");
                        name.peek();
                        System.out.println(name);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'D':
                    System.out.println((name.empty() == true) ? "stack is empty" : "Stack has value");
                    break;
                case 'E':
                    if(name.empty()) System.out.println("Stack is empty");
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Enter the String");
                        System.out.println((name.search(s.nextLine()) == -1) ? "The name is not in the stack":"name is present in the stack");
                        System.out.println(name);
                        
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Enter the correct option");
            }
            System.out.println("Do you want to continue? (y/n)");
            d = s.next().charAt(0);  
        }while(d == 'y');
}

public class NewClass{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        StackFunction s = new StackFunction();
    }
}
```

when i first receive this error i change the name of the program and class but even after that the error msg is still in there.

Answer (score 0):

There are some very basic mistakes here, maybe you should learn again about the basic things in Java, anyway, I am attaching the corrected code with comments.

```
public class NewClass{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        StackFunction s = new StackFunction();
        s.foo();
    }
}
```

```
// check all stack function (inbuilt)

import java.util.*;
class StackFunction{

    // create object and constructors

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    Stack<String> name = new Stack<String>();

    //declare/initialize values/variables;

    char opt,d;


    //program starts
public void foo(){//The block of code should be inside a function and not just in a class
    do{
        System.out.println("Enter your option:\n(A)push (B)pop (C)peek (D)empty (E)search (F)display");//you can use \n for new line,no need for more println than once in this case
        opt = s.next().charAt(0);
        switch(opt){
            case 'A':
                System.out.println("Push Option\nEnter the name:");
                name.push(s.next());
                System.out.println(name);
                break;
            case 'B':
                if(name.empty())
                {
                    System.out.println("Stack is empty");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Pop option");
                    String store = name.pop();
                    System.out.println("poped name: "+store);
                    System.out.println(name);
                }
                break;
            case 'C':
                if(name.empty()) System.out.println("Stack is empty");
                else{
                    System.out.println("Peak Value");
                    name.peek();
                    System.out.println(name);
                }
                break;
            case 'D':
                System.out.println((name.empty()) ? "stack is empty" : "Stack has value");
                break;
            case 'E':
                if(name.empty()) System.out.println("Stack is empty");
                else{
                    System.out.println("Enter the String");
                    System.out.println((name.search(s.nextLine()) == -1) ? "The name is not in the stack":"name is present in the stack");
                    System.out.println(name);
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Enter the correct option");
        }
        System.out.println("Do you want to continue? (y/n)");
        d = s.next().charAt(0);
    }while(d == 'y' || d=='Y');
}
}
```